# geoJson properties add/update

Tags: javascript, d3.js, leaflet, geojson

Is it somehow possible to dynamically add properties to features through d3 / leaflet.

I have this kind of GeoJson file:

```
        {"type":"Feature","id":"01","properties":
{"name":"Alabama","density":94.65, "news":22},
"geometry":{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":
[[[-87.359296,35.00118],[-85.606675,34.984749],[-85.431413,34.124869]...
```

And I would like to either update the news property when e.g. the user clicks on the feature or if news is not in this feature then add it. Is that possible?

Comment: Hi, I am more familiar with OpenLayers than Leaflet, but i gess your geojson is interpreted as features objects with attributes. Those object attributes can be edited, but you won't edit the geojsonfile itself.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's certainly possible: GeoJSON is a superset of JSON, which is represented in JavaScript as a normal object. To update a property of this GeoJSON feature if it was stored as the variable `feature`, you would write

```
feature.properties.news = 23;
```

Comment: okay that's great, and is it possible to create that new property if it is not already there e.g. feature.properties.add("news") or so?

Comment: The code is the same for updating a property versus adding a new one. `feature.properties.foobar = 10` would create a new property called `foobar` with a value of 10, or update the existing one.

Comment: Okay that worked very well but a new issue occured - the prop is only temporarily, how can i save the new file?

Comment: That is outside the scope of this question: JavaScript running in your web browser cannot save files to disk by itself.